# How can I get the same behavior in a WPF control/set of controls as that of HTML with links to other page content?

Tags: c#, wpf

In HTML I can add a link `<a href="#tagID">` that will jump to another tag with that id (i.e. `<div id="tagID">`).

In my WPF program I have a list of `GroupBox`es, currently inside a `ScrollViewer`. I want to be able to somehow click a link or button or have a way that will scroll the appropriate `GroupBox` to the top, much the same way as linking to IDs on an HTML page.

How can I get this functionality using WPF? Is there a control that will do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`FrameworkElement.BringIntoView()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.bringintoview(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
<Button Content="Go To GroupBox 10"
        Click="Button_Click"/>
```

Code Behind:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    GroupBox10.BringIntoView();
}
```